# how to apply filter without select?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply filter to a certain table without having to use Select. The are more than one tab, that's why i have to activate it.

my code is like that right now:

```
Worksheets("MY DATA").Activate
    Range("Data[#Headers]").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
```

The name of the tab I want to use is "MY DATA" as I said above. And the second line I get when I record a macro selecting all headers from my table. The range of it is A11 until P (all items of P, over 15 thousand)

any ideas?

Comment: Try `Worksheets("MY DATA").Range("Data[#Headers]").AutoFilter`

Comment: it didn't work. Any more ideas?